# At which point in time did Hinduism begin to embrace vegetarianism exactly?

Tags: history, brahmins, food, non-vegetarian

I was watching a BBC documentary where they claimed that early Rig Vedic writers (early Brahmins) practiced "horse sacrifice" and were indeed non vegetarians. So at what point did they decide to embrace vegetarianism and why? Was it because of Buddha or independently?

Comment: I will search for the documentary source if anyone wants

Comment: Veganism, Vegetarianism etc are all conspiracy created by westerns, not by Vedas. In Hinduism, anyone can eat meat after sacrificing the animals for god. Some animals are eligible for sacrifice and some are not.

Comment: [This article](http://www.mahavidya.ca/2010/08/19/vegetarianism-in-hinduism/) might help: “It is in Manu that we find the popular etymology of the term for meat: mam sah “me, he” (i.e., the animal whose flesh I eat in this life will devour me in the next world” (Bryant 197).

Comment: Soma yajnas were common in south India until the medieval times.

Comment: In the same documentary, the narrator implied that vegetarianism, or specifically, animal non-violence stemmed from Bhuddism. So was Buddha the origin of vegetarianism or was it already available in the vedas?